# How to prevent anchor tag from changing cursor to pointer?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let prevDom = null;

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);

document.body.style.cursor = "default !important";

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  e.target.style.pointerEvents = "none";
  if (prevDom !== null) {
    prevDom.style.pointerEvents = "";
  }
  prevDom = e.target;
}, false);
```

```html
<a href="/">click me!!!!</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="/">no click me!!!!</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="/">hahaha</a>
```

I'm making an extension that allows the user to highlight DOM elements by hovering on them. When the user is hovering, I want to disable click events and keep the cursor in its default state.
For that, I've added in the following code:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);

document.body.style.cursor = "default !important";
```

While this snippet prevents any click events from firing, it doesn't prevent the cursor from changing to pointer when hovering on anchor tags. I tried to simply disable pointer events when hovering on an element via an event listener for mousemove, but the issue here is that it flickers between the two states. Like, you see the pointer for a fraction of a second, before it switches to default. This really hampers the UX, so I was wondering if there's a way to prevent the cursor from changing to pointer.

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/1o42yf67/6/) to see an example

Comment: Does `document.body.style.pointerEvents = 'none'` work?

Comment: It works for the other elements, but not for anchor tags

Comment: You might need to add the style to the element itself, since it overrides the inherited default.

Comment: Add `e.target.style.cursor = 'default';`

Comment: Is there a reason why you dont use css? do you want an approach without css if not you can just use the css rule `a {cursor: default}`

Comment: @Gollasso adding the css rule you mentioned would work, but it would set the cursor to default for all anchor tags from the moment the stylesheet is injected. Since I want to let the user enable/disable the highlighting feature, I wanted a JS solution. It's okay though, Unmitigated's solution seems to work

Answer (score 1):

Use `cursor: default !important;`, but for the `a:hover` state as shown below.

If you need it to apply only to certain links on the page, use a class on the link and `a.yourclass:hover` in the CSS rule.

```css
a.myclass:hover {
  cursor: default !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="myclass">click me!!!!</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="myclass">no click me!!!!</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="myclass">hahaha</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS:

```
a:hover {
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to add an css rule for all anchor tags like this

```
a {

cursor: default;

}
```